# How do I shutdown/restart bionic beaver?

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, gnome-shell, restart

I just installed Bionic Beaver (Ubuntu 18.04), and I don't see how to shut it down or restart it from the GUI.  I had to shut it down from a terminal window.  I'm surely being stupid, but I need someone to tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top right corner of the screen, click the 'down' arrow, and a popup appears.  This includes a standard sort of power icon, which can be used to shutdown the machine, or put it to sleep.

Comment: Fun fact: if you press the ALT key while the menu is showing the power button changes into a Pause button (to let the computer fall asleep instead of shutdown).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not stupid, just blind.  I actually found that button before, but didn't notice the icons at the bottom of the popup.

Comment: Given that I occasionally cant find my own hands....

Answer (score 1):

Click the "**Activities**" button or press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and start typing "*shut down*" or "*power off*". An icon should appear. Click it and you should get a pop-up with shut down and restart options.